# Gulp Webpack not watching file in docker

Tags: docker, webpack, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a project node using docker. my project is built using gulp. when in local (not docker), watching for file change is working, but not in docker. how to solve this?

As additional information, I mount all files from local(windows) to docker.

Comment: Why bring Docker into it?  If the local-Node setup works, use it for day-to-day development.

Comment: @DavidMaze I work in a team, docker makes it easy to install in different environments.. yes, so I think I need it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question..

If you're experiencing the same thing as me, you can use a poll to have all files rechecked every few seconds (you decide)

below is the documentation

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionspoll